# How to make a React component setState() based on a Redux state change?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I *think* I know the answer to this, but just to make sure:

I want a React component to call `this.setState()` when the Redux state changes to a certain condition (say, `state.dataLoaded === true`). Should I somehow use `subscribe`, or is that too low level and I should instead use `connect` to map state to props? In which case, I assume something like this would be acceptable:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.dataLoaded) {
    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(nextProps.posts)
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You definitively should use `connect` to do this. When redux's state will change, new props will be generated and will trigger `componentWillReceiveProps`.

```js
class MyComp extends React.Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.dataLoaded) {
      this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(nextProps.posts)
      })
    }
  }
}

export default connect(
  state => ({
    dataLoaded: state.someStore.loaded
  })
)(MyComp)
```